Having trouble understanding this problem

A Paladrome is a special class of warriors derived from Paladins that are strong at holy magic. However, for a Paladin to achieve Paladrome level, they must be able to construct special spells. Each spell must be a palindrome, meaning that it is the same string when read forwards and back. The cost of constructing a new spell is based on rune pair costs (costs of adjacent letters) that occur in the final spell. Rune pairs not presented in the input are not allowed in the final spell. The total cost of a spell is the sum of all rune pair costs in the spell for each time the pair occurs in the spell.
For example, if the spell is abbaacaabba., then the cost is the sum of the costs of ab + ba + ac + ca + ab + ba.
Determine the smallest cost to make a new Paladrome spell of exactly a given length.
Input:
The first line of input contains two integers n (1 ≤ n ≤ 676) and k (2 ≤ k ≤ 100), where n is the number of rune pairs and k is the desired spell length in runes (i.e., letters). Each of the next n lines contains a string s (s consists of exactly two lower-case letters, which may be the same or different) and an integer c (1 ≤ c ≤ 100), where the string s is a rune pair, and c is the cost of that rune pair. All rune pairs are distinct.
Output:
Output a single integer, which is the smallest possible cost for constructing a spell of length k from the given runes, or -1 if it isn’t possible.
Sample input:
5 9  
ab 4  
ba 1  
bd 3  
db 100  
bc 4  

Sample output:
20


I am having trouble understanding this problem and I don't know where to start

Split it into smaller sub-problems and solve them one by one. You need to parse input, an algorithm to find out which pairs are palindromes of each other, an algorithm to find the combinations with the lowest cost etc.

Not a complete solution, but I am working on this now, and I have split it up into several sub-functions working my way outside-in. I would say you can do the same as your question, the main thing is that you need to understand where to start:

rune_cost_update(): Accepts the rune cost and store into DICTS with the corresponding rune keys
rune_cost = {
    "ab" : 4
    "ba" : 1
}


spell_calculate_cost():

Accepts temp string for candidate spell to determine cost
Stores it in a list to iterate through later to find MIN.


spell_palindrome_check():

Accepts individual rune_cost DICT values
Appends to existing spell
Reverses the temp string to check for palindrome
Returns Boolean


spell_append():

Accepts return from spell_palindrome_check()
And appends to Spell if addition satisfies palindrome check

Note: I want to make this correspond to spell_calculate_cost() in #2 above and maybe store as another DICT for "candidate" : cost pairing

spell_length_validation():

I'm stuck on this one.

I see from your example that "if the spell is abbaacaabba, then the cost is the sum of the costs of ab + ba + ac + ca + ab + ba"
However, the spell length in this example is 11 but the rune-pairs are supposed to be two-characters? I may be misunderstanding the problem - Are the adjacent-letter-pairs supposed to not overlap (in which case, the cost should be ab + ba + ac + aa + bb + a?) or are the supposed to (in which case, cost should be ab + bb + ba + aa....+ bb + ba). If either case, this function can use the output from spell_append() where the palindrome is being created to check against the user input length, pairs etc.





Sorry, mine is a WIP and I'm new to Python. If you are facing the issue of not knowing where to start as you've said, this is my approach where I have broken it down into smaller problems which I am testing with hardcoded candidate inputs to see if the code works.

Side note: This is interesting to me (as a newbie Pythonista and a not-so-newbie Fantasysta). If anyone has a source for the problem question or a source where I can get similar problems, I'd be interested.

Honestly, this is a really good first answer.  It's okay to not have a complete solution, as long as your answer contributes at least part of the solution, and you've certainly contributed, IMHO.  I've done some formatting clean-up to make it flow better that you can use as an example for the future.  I've also removed the "Can you clarify" question, as we tend to not to like to ask clarifying questions in an answer.  Finally, I moved the first paragraph to the end, as the "sidebar"/"side-note" should be secondary. Also rephrased as a statement.

Oh, I also remove the bolded sections.  That's best used for really important things like a warning that an action will irreversibly erase data (for instance).  Not a hard and fast rule, but you'll find most questions here use bold rarely, if at all.

@NotTheDr01ds : Hey thanks a tonne ! I'll keep the pointers in mind for the future.
